# Error: You attempted to set the key _i with the value 1 on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen., js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, react-native, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I can't find this error, why this error Occured, I never tried to change any immutable value

```
useEffect(() => {
    let dataPayload
    const clients = AWSIoTData.device({
      clientId: '',
      protocol: 'wss',
      accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
      secretKey: secretKey,
      keyPath: privatePathIs,
      certPath: certificatePathIs,
      caPath: caPathIs,
      host: host,
      port: 443,
      debug: true
    });


    clients.on('connect', function () {
      console.log('Connected');
      clients.subscribe(topic);
    });
    clients.on('reconnect', function () {
      console.log('reconnects');
      // clients.subscribe('example-topic');
    });

    clients.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error', err);
    });

    clients.on('message', async function (topic, payload) {
      var parsedData = JSON.parse(payload.toString());
      // let dataConvert = bin2String(payload)
      dataPayload = await VecMqttPayloadBeautify(topic, parsedData);

      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.SET_ALLDATA_PAYLOAD,
        payload: dataPayload,
      });
      // console.log('inner message', parsedData);
      // console.log('inner payload', dataPayload);
    });

  }, [])
```

connection is successfully build but this error

```
Error: You attempted to set the key `_i` with the value `1` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen., js engine: hermes
```

occured every time when page load, but if i used only one page code and triggered this function, after this there is no error, but when i use application navigator, stack navigator, then it shows error

Comment: Looks like the code you posted is not the source of the error, since `_i` doesn't exist in that code - you probably need to find the *actual* code that is throwing the error

Comment: yes you are absolutely right but whenever I add this code it will happen every time, if I remove this it will not,  if i build a one page mobile application and add all code in App.js THEN IT RUNS SUCCESSFULLY